# Not able to locate a class in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to locate a drop down arrow using this line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("icon-caret-down")).click();
```

There is nothing wrong with the code but the same class name is used for another drop down arrow which resides before it. My script points to that drop down arrow in spite me wanting it to point to this one.

I cannot use id or xpath as these are dynamically changed

[image]

Comment: If you have same class name for multiple elements, try using the unique property of the element. If it doesn't have one, try using the xpath

Comment: Show `HTML` code for the same

Comment: get all elements with that id (`findElements` instead of `findElement`) will give u a list of Elements. You can then loop trough the list and find something that identifies it.

Another thing you could try is working with css selectors as I guess the arrow you want to locate resides inside different html-tags then the first one

Comment: I can not use id or xpath as these are dynamically changed

Comment: Of course  you can use `XPath` in this case. Show `HTML` code of element you want to click

Answer (score 0):

Xpaths can be used if if the elements change dynamically but if you left with no other options, below snippet should help

```
List<WebElement> commonElem=driver.findElements(By.className("icon-caret-down"));
for(i=0;i<commonElem.size();i++){
    if(i=1){  //instead you can also use commonElem.getText()=="TextVal";
      commonElem.click();
      break;
    }
}
```